# installation for oracle weblogic server tools in eclipse indigo cannot complete

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I just wanted to use weblogic in my project,but I got the problem when I installed the new server runtime  enviroment in indigo 3.7.it shows bellow:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools
>   2.0.1.201203120349 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.weblogic.feature.group 2.0.1.201203120349)   >
>
> Missing requirement: Oracle Common Tools UI 4.2.1.201203120349 (oracle.eclipse.tools.common.ui 4.2.1.201203120349) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.draw2d [3.7.0,3.8.0)' but it could not be
>   found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Oracle Upgrade Framework 4.2.1.201203120349 (oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade 4.2.1.201203120349)
>       To: bundle oracle.eclipse.tools.common.ui [4.2.1,4.3.0)
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Oracle Common Tools 2.0.1.201203120349 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.common.feature.group 2.0.1.201203120349)
>       To: oracle.eclipse.tools.common.upgrade [4.2.1.201203120349]
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 2.0.1.201203120349 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.weblogic.feature.group
>   2.0.1.201203120349)
>       To: oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.common.feature.group 0.0.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

bundle org.eclipse.draw2d [3.7.0,3.8.0)'  it could not be found because the bundle draw2d is not in appropriate version

uninstall GEF plugin newer than version3.8

reinstall GET with this linkhttp://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates-pre-3_8/interim/ orhttp://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates-pre-3_8/milestones/ or http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates-pre-3_8/releases/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late to answer this, but anyhow, I think you would need the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE). You can find all versions here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-archive-1716547.html

Answer (score -1):

Go to the given below URL and just drag n drop INSTALL BUTTON in you eclipse

[Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12c (12.1.1.1) for Indigo](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-enterprise-pack-eclipse)